# Div content not accessible after css3 flip

Tags: css

I have the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wcZq7/

CSS:

```
.boxcontainer {
  perspective: 1000;
}

/* flip the pane when hovered */
.boxcontainer.hover .boxcard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.boxcontainer, .front, .back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.boxcard {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

After clicking the flip link once, I cannot click the links on the 'back' div, why is that?

Comment: @ruddy when I flip it, the 'back' is displayed, but stuff on the 'back' div are not accessible.. not sure how I answered my own question

Comment: I didnt look at the code properly, so my bad on that one. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/wcZq7/1/) - you can fix it by setting translateZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`translateZ` fixes this:

```
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wcZq7/3/)